# Do spinners natively allow int arrays in android?

Tags: android, user-interface, spinner

I've looked around but I couldn't find any answers.  Anyway, as the title says is there any way I can set a spinner from an int array in android?  For example what I am trying to do is set a max value ranging from 1 to any max number (i'll call it 'n') and the user has to select a number from one to the max number.

Right now I am trying to populate an int array from 1 to the max number, however that will take O(n) complexity and I cannot figure out how to actually put the int values in the spinner.  Can someone please help me out? thanks!

Comment: right now i am actually just using the adapter.add(number) and it works.  however i am not sure if this is the proper way of doing this.  is there a default way that doesnt have a complexity of O(n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array of strings with the string values of the ints--

that's the trivial way.

But for something like this I'd think about using a SeekBar

Comment: Seek bar would be cleaner and more user friendly.

Comment: yes, i didnt think of that!! hah thanks a lot, it is a lot more user friendly. Thanks!  I,ll accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use and array just like normal. Created your spinner and the spinners adapter and give the adapter the array full of the numbers up to `N`.